# How to get the user input and pass it to nsurl(swift)

Tags: swift

I am trying to get the user input(which will be url) and pass it to NSURL.

At the moment, I defined the url and initialised the nsurl.

What I need is to get the url from textfield and initialise with the nsurl.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`NSURL(string: self.myTextField.text)`

Answer (score 0):

As this is the first result on Google on how to get a NSURL from user input, I'd like to recommend that there's the [NSDataDetector API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatadetector?language=objc).

The benefit of this API is that it will work with anything that the User thinks is a URL and it'll provide the NSURL object from the match. `[NSURL URLWithString:aString]` really only works if the user is not lazy and enters a correct URL.

```
NSDataDetector* detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
__block NSString* input = _urlField.stringValue;
__block NSURL* url = nil;
[detector enumerateMatchesInString:input options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, input.length) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult * _Nullable result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    if (result != nil && result.resultType == NSTextCheckingTypeLink)
    {
        url = result.URL;
        // replace the input so that the scheme-check below can work on sane data
        input = [input substringWithRange:result.range];
    }
}];
if (url == nil) return;
// if the user did NOT explicitly start with http:
if ([url.scheme isEqual:@"http"] && input.length > @"http:".length && [[input substringToIndex:5] isEqual:@"http:"] == NO)
{
    NSURLComponents* comps = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:url resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];
    comps.scheme = @"https";
    url = comps.URL;
}
```